# Issue removing items from hash table that's currently rehashing

Tags: c++, hashtable

So I'm trying to work on this remove function in a test for robustness. It seems to work fine for smaller amounts of words but when adding hundreds and thousands it's falling flat. In the test, I add 900 words then remove 100 and that's where I first noticed the problem. It adds the words fine but it doesn't seem to remove them.

Based on my print statements I can tell this is happening in the part of the code that removes while the table is going through incremental rehashing into a new table.

Normally, I wouldn't post this much code but this is just the rehash if statement for remove and I have no idea where the problem is happening.

```
char * HashTable::remove(const char *str) 
{
  // if rehashing, check both tables
  // if not rehashing check if we need to
  // check new table if we have to rehash
  if (is_rehashing)
    {
      // first check in the old table
      // copy over any items we pass to new table
      int found = -1 ;
      char * cstring = NULL ;
      int index = hashCode(str) % m_tableSize ;
      int index2 = hashCode(str) % m_tableSize2 ;
      int count = 1;
      while (true)
        {
          if (m_hash[index] == NULL) { break ; } // not in first array
          if (m_hash[index] == DELETED) { } // not in this index
          else // its a cstring, copy over
            {
          //     int count = 1 ;
              int new_index = hashCode(m_hash[index]) % m_tableSize2 ;
              // insert to new table
              while( true )
                {
                  if (m_rehash[new_index] == NULL) break ;
                  if (m_rehash[new_index] == DELETED) break ;
                  new_index = (new_index + 1) % m_tableSize2 ;
                  count ++ ;
                }
              // copy to new table, and delete from old
              m_rehash[new_index] = strdup(m_hash[index]) ;
              m_size2++ ;
              free(m_hash[index]) ;
              m_hash[index] = NULL ;
              m_size-- ;



          if (strcmp(m_rehash[new_index], str) == 0) // FOUND!! now DELETE IT  
        {
          cstring = strdup(m_rehash[new_index]) ;
                  free(m_rehash[new_index]) ;
                  m_rehash[new_index] = DELETED ;
          found = 0 ;
        }
            }
          index = (index + 1) % m_tableSize ;
        }

      // iterate backwards, get the entire cluster.
      index = ((hashCode(str) % m_tableSize) - 1 ) %m_tableSize ;
      while (true)
        {
          if (m_hash[index] == NULL) { break ; } // not in first array
          if (m_hash[index] == DELETED) { } // not in this index
          else  // found a cstring
            {
              //              int count = 1 ;
              int new_index = hashCode(m_hash[index]) % m_tableSize2 ;
              // insert to new table TODO: maybe make a new function for this
              while( true )
                {
                  if (m_rehash[new_index] == NULL) break ;
                  if (m_rehash[new_index] == DELETED) break ;
                  new_index = (new_index + 1) % m_tableSize2 ;
                  count ++ ;
                }
              // copy to new table, and delete from old
              m_rehash[new_index] = strdup(m_hash[index]) ;
              m_size2++ ;
              free(m_hash[index]) ;
              m_hash[index] = NULL ;
              m_size-- ;

              // check if 2nd table needs rehashing
              //if (count >= 10) { rehash() ; }
              //else if (m_size2 >= (m_tableSize2 / 2)) { rehash() ; }
              // found it!
              if (strcmp(m_rehash[new_index], str) == 0) { found = new_index ; }
            }
          index = (index - 1) % m_tableSize ;
        }

      // check if 2nd table needs rehashing
      if (count >= 10) { rehash() ; }
      else if (m_size2 >= (m_tableSize2 / 2)) { rehash() ; }

      if (found != -1) 
    {
      finishRehash() ; 
      return cstring ; 
    }

      // couldn't find it in the 1st array, lets try the second
      count = 1 ;
      while (true)
        {
          if (m_rehash[index2] == NULL) { finishRehash() ; return NULL ; } 
      // not in either array
          if (m_rehash[index2] == DELETED) { } // nada
          else if (strcmp(m_rehash[index2], str) == 0)  // FOUND HERE
        { 
          char * cstring = strdup(m_rehash[index2]) ;
          free(m_rehash[index2]) ;
          m_rehash[index2] = DELETED ;
          finishRehash() ;
          return cstring;
        }
          index2 = (index2 + 1) % m_tableSize2 ;
          count++ ;
        }
      if (count >= 10) { rehash() ; }
      else if (m_size2 >= (m_tableSize2 / 2)) { rehash() ; }
    }
```

any input would be super helpful thank you!!

Comment: Shouldn't the rehashing be atomic with respect to other operations?  I'm not sure I see the utility in allowing anyone to access a hash table while it is rehashing itself.

Comment: the way i understand it, in the incremental rehash there’s both the old and new table. a remove operation will have to look in both tables and remove the item from the appropriate one. During the incremental rehash phase, every operation (i.e., insert, find and remove) will also move a few items from the old table to the new table. After a number of operations, most of the items will have migrated to the new table. The stragglers in the old table will be moved to the new table and the old table can be discarded.

Comment: `strdup` and `free` in a C++ program?  Have you tried `std::unordered_map`, which is a hash table?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why strdup then free the source rather than just assigning the pointer?

Comment: so i'm coding this according to certain restrictions and one is that i gotta use strdup and free unfortunately :(

Comment: Expressions like `index = ((hashCode(str) % m_tableSize) - 1 ) %m_tableSize` or `index = (index - 1) % m_tableSize ` can result in an index of `-1`

Comment: what do you suggest? bc it might go over so i have the -1 there but idk how to get around that ive been staring at this for so long lmao i think my head broke